# Can I train Word2vec using a Stacked Autoencoder with non-linearities?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, word2vec, autoencoder

Every time I read about Word2vec, the embedding is obtained with a very simple Autoencoder: just one hidden layer, linear activation for the initial layer, and softmax for the output layer.

My question is: why can't I train some Word2vec model using a stacked Autoencoder, with several hidden layers with fancier activation functions? (The softmax at the output would be kept, of course.)

I never found any explanation about this, therefore any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word vectors are noting but hidden states of a neural network trying to get good at something.

To answer your question
Of course you can.

If you are going to do it why not use fancier networks/encoders as well like `BiLSTM` or `Transformers`.

This is what people who created things like `ElMo` and `BERT` did(though their networks were a lot fancier).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assume that training fancier architectures would require a massive amount of computational power. Is it something doable on platforms like GCP or AWS perhaps?

Comment: Yes it is doable on AWS or GCP